# Do (non-callback) function expressions have to be assigned to a variable?

Tags: javascript

Do function expressions have to be assigned to a variable (when used in a regular context)? I'm aware they don't need to be when they're callbacks (passed as a parameter of another function), or used in an IIFE, for starters.

If they do, it seems like their MDN [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) would make this more front and center in this description:

> A function expression is very similar to and has almost the same
>   syntax as a function statement (see function statement for details).
>   The main difference between a function expression and a function
>   statement is the function name, which can be omitted in function
>   expressions to create anonymous functions.

Also, while on that same MDN page the variable assignment is included in the syntax:

```
> var myFunction = function [name]([param1[, param2[, ..., paramN]]]) { 
> statements };
```

In their [chapter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) on functions, the variable assignment isn't included (nevermind the missing semicolon):

```
function [name]([param[, param[, ... param]]]) {
   statements
}
```

Comment: the semicolon in the last code isn't **missing** at all, it should not be there, and it isn't ... and you dont' assign a [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) to a variable, because that would make it a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) - I think the part you posted in yellow makes perfect sense, and does not need any more explanation at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't have to be assigned to a variable. For example, here's a function that gets evaluated as an expression that's not a callback:

```js
(
  () => void 0
);
```

It's just an orphaned expression that's not doing anything, kind of like

```js
5;
```

That said, while the above are *technically* legal, they're pretty useless. A function expression doesn't *have* to be used (such as an assignment to a variable or as a parameter), but if it's not used, there's not much point.